# Lower volume of AVAudioPlayer sound

Tags: ios, cocoa, audio, avaudioplayer

I have a background song that I use on an infinite loop while my app is in use.
Except that the sound/volume is too high... I'd like it to be played at half the volume... This is how I load the music:

```
//background music for in-game loop
backgroundLoop = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Background" ofType:@"wav"];
GameMusic = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:backgroundLoop] error:NULL];
GameMusic.delegate = self;          //need <...> in .h
GameMusic.numberOfLoops = -1;       //play infinite loop
```

I've tried a few things, but nothing affects the volume of the track. I've tried this:

```
GameMusic.volume = 0.5f;
```

and:

```
[GameMusic setVolume: 0.5f];
```

but it doesn't change the volume and still plays at the same max volume...

The strange thing is, if I set the volume to 0.0 (`[GameMusic setVolume: 0.5f];`) it doesn't play at all because I'm guessing it's setting volume to zero... but why does `0.1f` or `0.5f` not adjust the volume when it's a linear scale from 0-1?

How can I lower the volume of the sound? It's far too loud.

Also, I tried editing the actual sounds in Garageband, but they won't export any sounds under a second long so it's not feasible to adjust them manually.

Thanks.

**Update**

[A Wiki](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Playing_Audio_on_iOS_7_using_AVAudioPlayer), shows the following file formats are supported:

`- AAC (MPEG-4 Advanced Audio Coding)
 - ALAC (Apple Lossless)
 - AMR (Adaptive Multi-rate)
 - HE-AAC (MPEG-4 High Efficiency AAC)
 - iLBC (internet Low Bit Rate Codec)
 - Linear PCM (uncompressed, linear pulse code modulation)
 - MP3 (MPEG-1 audio layer 3)
 - µ-law and a-law`

Unfortunately, I changed my `.wav` to a `.mp3` and it still isn't working :(

Comment: "when it's a linear scale" I wouldn't assume that if I were you. Decibels are logarithmic...

Comment: That's what the Apple documentation states in the AVAudioPlayer Class, so I went with it.

Comment: Hmm, I see what you mean. I wonder what they mean by that? Still, since you say the original is "far too loud", I'd recommend trying some smaller values like `0.05f` and see if that helps. Just a wild idea...

Comment: @matt Just to let you know, I tried what you said, and set `GameMusic.volume = 0.01f` and it works. The file formats must be one of the listed above though (I used Mp3's) as wav formats are not supported. Thanks for mentioning it.

Comment: Cool! I will give that as an answer.

Comment: The funny thing is, for me, even setting the volume straight to 0.0 (zero) has no effect at all. How buggy can the most basic stuff be?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I suspect that it is working but, because the sound is so loud to start with, you are not perceiving the difference (because of the logarithmic nature of the decibel scale of intensities). Try a much smaller number, such as `0.05`, perhaps.

Answer (score 3):

It's finally working. The volume is adjusted by using lower linear values such as `0.01f` and `0.08f`.

I changed my file type to `mp3` as `wav` isn't supported:

```
    backgroundLoop = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Background" ofType:@"mp3"];
```

and then set the volume of the loaded audio:

```
    GameMusic.volume = 0.01f
```

and `0.01f` cuts the volume in half (approximately by my ears), but may be different depending on what track is used, if it's normalised or what file format it's encoded in.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting errors in Swift 3.0 using this syntax.  I resolved it by trial and error.  Use the following to adjust the volumes:

nameOfFile.volume = 1.0

Drop the "f".  Anything above 1.0 will increase the volume, below will decrease.  Hope this helps.  Cheers.